# One variable doesn't get transferred from test fragment to another test fragment

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have the following test plan:

Short story (what's important from that test plan):

"**Get number files**" gets the total number of files from a given path.
Content of BeanShell Sampler:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;

File folder = new File(vars.get("path"));
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
int counter = 0;
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.getName().toString().contains(".xml") == true){
        counter++;
    }

}

String counterStr = Integer.toString(counter);  

vars.put("counter",counterStr);

log.info("Output_counterStr:"+counterStr);
```

**Get number of current document** : It is a counter that gets the next file (for upload) Content of BeanShell Sampler:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;    

String fName = null;    
int currentDoc = 0;
fName = vars.get("filename");
log.info("Output_fName:"+fName);

if (fName.contains("00")==true){    
    currentDoc = 0;
    currentDoc ++;
} else {    
    currentDoc ++;
}

String currentDocStr = Integer.toString(currentDoc); 

vars.put("currentDoc",currentDocStr);

log.info("Output_currentDoc:"+currentDocStr);
```

What I want to obtain is to use the value of *currentDoc* down in *WebSocket request-response Sampler*. As following:

```
<currentDocument>${currentDoc}</currentDocument>
<totalDocuments>${counter}</totalDocuments>
```

The problem is that ${counter} actually has a value while ${currentDoc} arrives as it is. Any idea what can be wrong? You can't have that value transported into another test fragment? (The counter is incremented by calling a Module controller inside the "while" function).

Thank you

Comment: are you sure you are not getting any exceptions in the `Get number of current document`? that could cause var to not be stored. For example if `fName = vars.get("filename");` does not return a value, then `fName.contains` will cause a `NullPointerException`, so nothing will be stored. Maybe try to add `if(fName != null && fName.contains...)` to check on that possibility. Also some compilers may not like space before `++` in `currentDoc ++`

Comment: Thank you @KirilS. for your time. I manage to make it work but now I am facing another problem. I manage to make it work by using bsh.shared.var for currentDoc. The problem was that the variable declaration was outside the test fragment (as it was used for counting) and I couldn't use it inside (every iteration would reset the variable).